# Zend DB atomic transactions

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, transactions

I have to perform a group of SQL operations that either survive together or die together.
So that if any part of my statement/s fail, the entire process is rolled back to the beginning as if the transaction never took place.

without zend I would do:

```
$conn->query('BEGIN');
$conn->query($myQuery);
//rollback if anything went wrong
$conn->query('COMMIT');
```

In Zend I created the Db connection in my bootstrap:

```
    protected function _initDb()
{
    $config=Zend_registry::get('config');
    $db = Zend_Db::factory($config->resources->db->adapter, $config->resources->db->params);  
    //set default adapter         
    Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db); 
    Zend_Registry::set("db", $db);  
}
```

And interactions with Db are made by models classes (extending Zend_Db_Table_abstract)

```
class Platform extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
 public function insertPlatform($x)
 {
  $this->insert($x);
 }
}
class Game extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
 public function insertGame($x)
 {
  $this->insert($x);
 }
}
```

**How could I achieve the same (survive together or die together)in Zend?**

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend_Db wraps the transaction functionality too. So there is nothing different in using it with or without ZF.

You find ZF transactions explained in the [Adapter Section of the Zend_Db Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.transactions). Look for the paragraph 'Controlling Database Transactions'.